# jQuery not finding element using id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a simple HTML form and for some reason jQuery cannot find the element I'm looking for.

HTML:

```
    <form id="form">
                            <fieldset>
                    <table>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="label">Street</td>
                            <td class="field"><input type="text" size="50" value="" id="s.street"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
        <fieldset>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="label">Street</td>
                            <td class="field"><input type="text" size="50" value="" id="b.street"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
        </form>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(
                function() {

                    $("input[id='s.street']").keyup(function() {
                    $('#b.street').val($(this).val());

                    });
});
```

I get no errors in the console log.

Comment: `$('#b.street')` says find me the element with the id of "b" and it also must have a class of "street". Read the docs on jQuery selectors.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

from here: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) it looks like jquery has trouble with ids that have periods and colons. so try removing those and see if it works.

Comment: The reference correctly says the ID is valid with the `.`, so while not a good idea, it is not the actual problem.

Comment: "As noted in other responses, jQuery has problems with ids that contain periods and colons." is from the reference.

Answer (score 4):

If the element HAS to have that exact id, use:

```
$('#b\\.street')​
```

Answer (score 2):

ID's should be unique, so you shouldn't have to filter with the input tag.  Additionally, you need to add an escape sequence before the `.` in your ID name.  `$('#s\\.street')` is the correct selector.  I would actually suggest not using the `.`...

Comment: Absolutely.. if possible get rid of the '.'.. or 'period' as the americans call it (At 29 I still chuckle when calling a full stop a period).

Answer (score 0):

your id names conflict with the jquery selector syntax.

When defining an id for an element do not use the # . or any spaces within your ID

Answer (score 0):

YOu have a problem in your naming convention. replace the `.` in the name to a hyphen.

So:

```
<input type="text" size="50" value="" id="s.street">
```

Becomes

```
<input type="text" size="50" value="" id="s-street">
```

and you select in with jquery like so:

```
$("#s-street");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sizzle (the javascript selector library that jQuery implements) will see the `s.street` as an element `s` or `b` with a class of `street`. as opposed to an element with id of `s.street`.